# Make div dropdown navbar elements the same size and position as hyperlink navbar elements

Tags: html, css

I'm working on [a website for my friend](https://sawakotomiko.github.io/). If you're interested in the full source code, you can see it [here](https://github.com/SawakoTomiko/SawakoTomiko.github.io). Currently, our `div` dropdown navbar elements are a different height and y position than our `a` hyperlink navbar elements, despite having nearly identical CSS applied to them.

Here's my code (appears to have messier spacing than our actual code because I just copied parts of it):

```css
/* formatting of links */

p, a {
    color: #5e2800;
    font-family: courier;
    font-size: 15px;
}

a {
    color: brown;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li {
    color: #5e2800;
    font-family: courier;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.nav {
    color: brown;
    font-family: courier;
    font-size: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;    
}

/* search bar */

.topnav input[type="text"] {
    float: right;
    padding: 6px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 10px;
}

/* dropdown */

.dropdown {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  color: brown;
  font-family: courier;    
  font-size: 15px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
        <div class="nav">
            <a href="/info">Information</a>
            <a href="/gallery">Gallery</a>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">
                    Members
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">
                    Events
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
            <div class="topnav">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
        </div>
```

So far, we've tried to make the dropdown elements convert to also be `a` tags, but this had no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The little bit of Googling I did seems to indicate that using `overflow: hidden` "can" change the baseline of an element, so removing `overflow: hidden;` from `.dropdown` fixes that if your overall design will tolerate that.

```css
/* formatting of links */

p, a {
    color: #5e2800;
    font-family: courier;
    font-size: 15px;
}

a {
    color: brown;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li {
    color: #5e2800;
    font-family: courier;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.nav {
    color: brown;
    font-family: courier;
    font-size: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;    
}

/* search bar */

.topnav input[type="text"] {
    float: right;
    padding: 6px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 10px;
}

/* dropdown */

.dropdown {
  /* overflow: hidden;            <--------- Remove this     */
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  color: brown;
  font-family: courier;    
  font-size: 15px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
            <a href="/info">Information</a>
            <a href="/gallery">Gallery</a>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">
                    Members
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">
                    Events
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
            <div class="topnav">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
        </div>
```